# ApplePay > Hide pop up after card selection

Tags: applepay, applepay-web

I am creating a form where a user can pay using Apple Pay.
Once a card is selected, I want to the ApplePay pop up to dissapear so that the user can enter other details on the form before the form is submitted. I want to show a final confirmation page before I send the payload to authorise a payment.
I am using `onpaymentauthorized` and calling `session.completePayment` to close the pop up. But this show the user that the payment has been authorised.

Q: After I receive the encrypted payload from Apple, how can I hide the pop up without showing the user that the payment has been authorised?

I've tried to use other methods like `onpaymentmethodselected` but this does not give me the ApplePay payload.